# Ubuntu 22.04 (budgie desktop) OS works perfectly if no external monitor is plugged in, otherwise the external screen is black and the OS is SLOW

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, laptop, hp

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 in an external SSD. the operating system is working properly. I am using a laptop to run the operating system. Upon installing the OS, an external monitor that I use at work (HP M24f FHD) which is connected via HDMI was working properly, the only change I made was to assign a different color profile because the colors were messed up. I attempted to use my laptop using a different set up. Two completely different monitors connected to the same laptop via USB-C. again the colors were not properly set up and upon trying to assign a color profile to each monitor and not being able to adjust it I shut down the system. after that, I started the OS, using the first set up I was using when I installed Ubuntu and now the Screen which was properly working at first is just black. Ubuntu is recognizing the monitor as I am able to move the cursor to the black screen and it is also detected under the display settings, however, that is not the only issue, now, Ubuntu is extremely slow. If unplug the HDMI cable and use Ubuntu on my laptop only the OS runs fine. I have tried to reboot the system, connect and reconnect the monitor and use a different HDMI, run update and upgrade commands and nothing has worked.

Upon installation I did two things, however these changes did seem not affect anything as the OS was still working properly after multiple reboots and disconnecting the external monitor multiple times:

set up Budgie Desktop

Download VSCode.

Laptop specs:

- Processor:    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
- Installed RAM:    16.0 GB (15.8 GB usable)
- System type:  64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Pen and touch:    No pen or touch input is available for this display.